# sql date-time comparison of people

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, time, between

I want to make a list of people when they are working without a chef.

sql table:

```
people_id clock_in               clock_out
1         2016-10-10 06:58:01.000 2016-10-10 14:59:01.000 
1         2016-10-11 06:57:02.000 2016-10-11 14:58:23.000 
..
2         2016-10-10 07:51:01.000 2016-10-10 13:00:01.000
```

People_id: 1 = normal working man and 2 = chef in this example

now I want to display the time when 1 is working when 2 isn't there

Like this:

```
people_id start_working_without_chef end_working_without_chef
1         2016-10-10 06:58:01.000    2016-10-10 07:51:01.000
1         2016-10-10 13:00:01.000    2016-10-10 14:59:01.000
```

In this example there is just one working man and one chef but this must be extended to serveral working mens  and serveral chiefs

How can I make a sql query to solve this problem.

Comment: Last row (`people_id = 2`) time is between 1st row time so that does not mean chef is working when normal man working ?

Comment: Can you add a few more rows of sample table data, and adjust the expected result?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name sql 2008 r2

Comment: @Prdp That's correct. I want to display the time when someone is working without a chef.

Comment: I think there should be a third row to your output now; `1    2016-10-11 06:57:02.000 2016-10-11 14:58:23.000` as no chef is available at this time

Comment: If you have more people and more chefs, how does `people_id` change? If every person/chef has a unique value for `people_id` you will need some other flag e.g. `is_chef` or foreign reference to a `person_type` table. Unless `people_id` can only ever be 1 or 2?

Answer (score 0):

well it's not really "nice" looking, i'll try tomorrow to find a better solution.

```
create table tt (id int, dte_in timestamp, dte_out timestamp);

insert into tt values (1, timestamp('2016-10-10-06.58.01'), timestamp('2016-10-10-14.59.01'));
insert into tt values (1, timestamp('2016-10-11 06:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-11 14:58:23'));
insert into tt values (1, timestamp('2016-10-12 06:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-12 14:58:23'));
insert into tt values (1, timestamp('2016-10-13 06:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-13 14:58:23'));
insert into tt values (1, timestamp('2016-10-14 06:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-14 14:58:23'));
insert into tt values (2, timestamp('2016-10-10 07:51:01'), timestamp('2016-10-10 13:00:01'));
insert into tt values (2, timestamp('2016-10-12 05:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-12 15:58:23'));
insert into tt values (2, timestamp('2016-10-13 05:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-13 12:58:23'));
insert into tt values (2, timestamp('2016-10-14 10:57:02'), timestamp('2016-10-14 16:58:23'));


select a.id, 
 a.dte_in,
 b.dte_in
from tt a
inner join tt b on b.id = 2 and b.dte_in between a.dte_in and a.dte_out 
where a.id = 1
union all
select a.id, 
 b.dte_out,
 a.dte_out
from tt a
inner join tt b on b.id = 2 and b.dte_out between a.dte_in and a.dte_out 
where a.id = 1
union all
select a.id, a.dte_in, a.dte_out
from tt a
where a.id = 1 and not exists (select 1 from tt b where b.id = 2 and b.dte_in between a.dte_in and a.dte_out) 
and not exists (select 1 from tt b where b.id = 2 and a.dte_in between b.dte_in and b.dte_out)
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! But how can I make it so that I have a group of people that I want to compare with a group of chefs. So I can display the times when there is someone working without any chef available.